# Is there any ways to convert hash data from digest version to hexdigest version

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

I want to get a value in string format from library I currently use.

Right now the library return a value in bytes type but I want to get it in string types. So I use bytes.decode() to convert it but it gave an errors because it cannot decode some characters.

I digged into how the library work. Turned out it use this method to provide a hash and return the value back

```
hashlib.sha256(data).digest()
```

an example of value is

```
b'\xce\xe00-Y\x84M2\xbd\xca\x91\\\x82\x03\xddD\xb3?\xbb~\xdc\
```

then I decode it and got an error.

So is there any way to turn it back to string type or I have to create my own version of hash data and use hexdigest() instead.

****Edited**

give a real example of an error

```
b'\xce\xe00-Y\x84M2\xbd\xca\x91\\\x82\x03\xddD\xb3?\xbb~\xdc\x19\x05\x1e\xa3z\xbe\xdf(\xec\xd4r'
```

return this error

```
*** UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: "_got an error_": Please include the complete error message in your question.

Comment: I think the example given isn't complete... copy+paste error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `binacii.hexlify`:

```
import binascii
binary_string = b'\xce\xe00-Y\x84M2\xbd\xca\x91\\\x82\x03\xddD\xb3?\xbb~\xdc'
hex_string = binascii.hexlify(binary_string)
print(hex_string)
```

outputs:

```
b'cee0302d59844d32bdca915c8203dd44b33fbb7edc'
```

Comment: @Semooze Great! Feel free to mark this answer as correct (if you think it is).

Answer (score 2):

If the value is returning digest as you have mentioned above,

```
hashlib.sha256(data).digest()
```

Then to get the hexdigest of this, 
you can use the following code,

```
hex_digest = digest.encode('hex').decode()
```

example :

```
digest = b'\xce\xe00-Y\x84M2\xbd\xca\x91\\\x82\x03\xddD\xb3?\xbb~\xdc'
hex_digest = digest.encode('hex').decode()
print(hex_digest)

u'cee0302d59844d32bdca915c8203dd44b33fbb7edc'
```